# Getting the number of unique values in a specific line location in a large text file

Tags: perl, awk, grep

All,

I have a large server log with contains the entry: 
 not found from Module

Immediately after it is a quotation mark followed location of a module. The file is over 4,800 lines long, and each module may appear over 100 times. So, what I'd like to do is something like a wc -l, but then to only show me the number of unique values in the module name portion of the server log.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use `uniq -c` to get a count of all the unique values?

Comment: Is a "a quotation mark" a single quote `'` or a doube quote `"` and is there a matching one at the end of the Module id? Post some small, representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -oP '(?<=not found from Module ")[^"]+(?=")' logfile | sort -u | wc -l`

Answer (score 3):

```
grep 'entry: not found from Module' logfile | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus Yep, just fixed it. I just wanted to point out with my answer that there's probably no need for Perl regex here.

Comment: Well, it's possible that there is other information on the line than just the module name, so it would be safest to extract just the module names themselves rather than the entire lines containing them.

Comment: @Ed: Great, I did not know about that option.

Comment: The usual reason for using sort and uniq in a pipe is just when you want a count of each unique entry so then you'd have `sort | uniq -c`. I think MAYBE that's actually more in line with what the OP wants, i.e. to get a count of each Module name, rather than piping all of the output to `wc -l` to get a count of ALL of the "not found" lines.

Comment: @EdMorton `show me the number of unique values in the module name portion of the server log` -- I'm more inclined to think this means just the number of modules mentioned.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ah, looks like you're right since the OP selected an answer based on that as the correct one. Odd that he didn't choose your simpler answer in the same vein.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nlwe '$a{$_}++ }{ print "$_ : $a{$_}" for keys %a' log.txt
```

Create a hash key for each line, then print the keys at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{count[$NF]++} END{ for (mod in count) print mod, count[mod] }' file
```

is probably close to what you want but it's hard to guess without some sample input and expected output.